# how to add styles to actionview helper tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionviewhelper

how do i add styles to actionviews helper tags. like the following

```
<%= link_to "Home", :controller=> "home", :action=> "index", :style=>{:position=>"absolute", :top=>"0px"} %>
```

is something like the above achievable. I dont want to add css classes.

Thanks.

**Update**-- sorry **Salil**. it doesn't work for link_to_remote. I need a solution that works for any helper tag

```
<%= link_to_remote "Next", :style=>"float:right;", :update=>"uxUpdateDiv", :url=>{:controller=> "home", :action=> "next"}, :before=> "jQuery('#uxcLoader').css('display','block'); jQuery('#uxOverLay').css('display','block');",:success=> "jQuery('#uxcLoader').css('display','none'); jQuery('#uxOverLay').css('display','none');" %>
```

the style doesn't seem to be applied at all...!! even a **style** attribute is not formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you an do it in following way

```
<%= link_to "Home", {:controller=> "home", :action=> "index"}, :style=>"position:absolute;top:0px" %>
```

This will create following HTML

```
<a href="/home" style="position: absolute; top: 0px;">Home</a>
```

It depends on which tag you are using for some tag you have to add **:html>{}**

For link_to_remote you have to write

```
<%= link_to_remote "Next", 
                :update=>"uxUpdateDiv", 
                :url=>{:controller=> "home", :action=> "next"}, 
                :html=>{:style=>"float:right;"},
                :before=> "jQuery('#uxcLoader').css('display','block'); jQuery('#uxOverLay').css('display','block');",
                :success=> "jQuery('#uxcLoader').css('display','none'); jQuery('#uxOverLay').css('display','none');" %>
```

this will create following html check it out.

```
<a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#uxcLoader').css('display','block'); jQuery('#uxOverLay').css('display','block');; new Ajax.Updater('uxUpdateDiv', '/home/next', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, onSuccess:function(request){jQuery('#uxcLoader').css('display','none'); jQuery('#uxOverLay').css('display','none');}}); return false;" style="float: right;">Next</a>
```

Comment: no it depends on tag you are using for some tag you have to use :html for some tags you have to apply style directly.